# Getting existing address while deploying contract on polygon mumbai using hardhat

Tags: contract-deployment, polygon, hardhat-deploy

I deployed a contract on polygon mumbai using hardhat and later when i verify the contract, i got this error

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 has no bytecode. Is the contract deployed to this network?
The selected network is polygon_mumbai
```

Then i looked upto the address on mumbai polygonscan then i found that this address already exists.
How is it possible? And what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that the address "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F051" is an eoa and not a contract, have you double-checked that the deployed address is this one?

Comment: Yes, i have double-checked it.